# CSRF configuration on spring-cloud-gateway for Angular

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway, csrf-token

I tried to adapt [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/exploits.html#_i_am_using_angularjs_or_another_javascript_framework) for reactive applications (spring-cloud-gateway used as BFF) and have configured it as an OAuth2 client with:

```java
http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        .csrfTokenRequestHandler(new XorServerCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler()::handle);
```

but I still had a "An expected CSRF token cannot be found" error, and actually, I couldn't find the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie is my browser debugging tools.

I then defined such a `WebFilter`:

```java
@Bean
WebFilter csrfCookieWebFilter() {
    return (exchange, chain) -> {
        Mono<CsrfToken> csrfToken = exchange.getAttributeOrDefault(CsrfToken.class.getName(), Mono.empty());
        return csrfToken.doOnSuccess(token -> {
        }).then(chain.filter(exchange));
    };
}
```

I now have a XSRF-TOKEN cookie, but also an "Invalid CSRF Token" error.

So, what is the `CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository` exactly and why couldn't I find the CSRF token cookie with it on spring-cloud-gateway?

How should I configure my spring-cloud-gateway to allow PUT requests to the `/logout` endpoint from an Angular application?

### Edit

As a very similar question was asked more than 1.5 month ago but is still unanswered: "[Angular app served behind Spring Cloud Gateway cannot send POST requests to backend because of invalid CSRF token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75298306/angular-app-served-behind-spring-cloud-gateway-cannot-send-post-requests-to-back)", I opened a ticket for spring-security: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12871

The other question is missing the part in the doc I linked, but still, it should produce a CSRF cookie (even if the value then fails to be validated because of the new BREACH proof handler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: RTFM and double check the `CsrfToken` you imported (there is one for WebMVC and a different one from another package for WebFlux)

## Having the CSRF cookie set

Since Spring Boot 3 (spring-security 6), it is mandatory to provide with a filter to add the CSRF cookie to the response. The `Cookie(Server)CsrfTokenRepository` is not enough any more.

This is documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/exploits.html#_i_am_using_a_single_page_application_with_cookiecsrftokenrepository) for servlets and [there](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/reactive.html#_i_am_using_angularjs_or_another_javascript_framework) for reactive applications. **This doc contains the exact configuration to copy / paste for each case**.

Also, be very careful to import the right `CsrfToken` depending on the nature of your application or the token will be null: the request / exchange attribute with has `CsrfToken.class.getName()` as name and you could import the one from `org.springframework.security.web.csrf` or `org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf` without any compilation error (the first is to be used in servlet and the second in webflux). **This was the reason why the cookie was not set after I added the filter: I had the import for servlet referenced in a `WebFilter` => the CSRF token value was not resolved**.

## Having the CSRF token correctly validated

As stated in the doc, the `handle` method of a `Xor(Server)CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler` should be used as csrf request handler (only the `handle` method, not the full `Xor(Server)CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler` instance)

## Complete sample

The `gateway` module of the [**B**ackend **F**or **F**rontend tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff) in [this serie](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) is a `spring-cloud-gateway` securing requests from an Angular application with sessions (and CSRF protection). This module using a [Spring Boot starter of mine](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons), the above configuration is controlled by a single configuration property: `com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.client.csrf=cookie-accessible-from-js`. Refer to the starter source code [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/b083548c5e10e40fc61b1436a3db668adafbec59/webflux/spring-addons-webflux-core/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oauth2/config/reactive/ReactiveConfigurationSupport.java#L93) and [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/b083548c5e10e40fc61b1436a3db668adafbec59/webflux/spring-addons-webflux-client/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oauth2/config/reactive/SpringAddonsOAuth2ClientBeans.java#L275) for Java configuration:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain clientSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    ...
    http.csrf(csrf -> {
        var delegate = new XorServerCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
        csrf.csrfTokenRepository(CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).csrfTokenRequestHandler(delegate::handle);
    }
    ...
}

@Bean
WebFilter csrfCookieWebFilter() {
    return (exchange, chain) -> {
        Mono<CsrfToken> csrfToken = exchange.getAttributeOrDefault(CsrfToken.class.getName(), Mono.empty());
        return csrfToken.doOnSuccess(token -> {
        }).then(chain.filter(exchange));
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a Spring Cloud Gateway application that also handles OAuth2 authentication.
Application front end is written in Angular.

I was struggling for a while to implement CSRF protection. I had two issues.

**1. CSRF token was not set for user invoking requests.**
I found out that in Spring Boot 3 Reactive applications, CSRF tokens are not set eagerly for requests. Source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6046#issuecomment-437080518

I solved the issue by adding a cookie filter to subscribe to the token for every request.

```
 @Bean
  public WebFilter csrfCookieWebFilter() {
    return (exchange, chain) -> {
      Mono<CsrfToken> csrfToken = exchange.getAttributeOrDefault(CsrfToken.class.getName(), Mono.empty());
      return csrfToken.doOnSuccess(token -> {
        /* Ensures the token is subscribed to. */
      }).then(chain.filter(exchange));
    };
  }
```

**2. CSRF token is not read from cookie and set to header.**
Angular passes CSRF cookie in **X-XSRF-TOKEN** header, by default.
It took me ages to figure it out that Angular will add the X-XSRF-TOKEN header only if the XSRF-TOKEN cookie was generated server-side with the following options:

- Path = /
- httpOnly = false

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50511663/10491248

I did not set path to "/", after adding that to my tokenRepository CSRF token was successfully parsed from header.

This is how I implemented setting CSRF config for ServerHttpSecurity:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
...

  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain filterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    ...
    setCsrfConf(http);

    return http.build();
  }
  ...

  private void setCsrfConf(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository tokenRepository = CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
    tokenRepository.setCookiePath("/");
    XorServerCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler delegate = new XorServerCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
    ServerCsrfTokenRequestHandler requestHandler = delegate::handle;
    http.csrf(csrf -> csrf
        .csrfTokenRepository(tokenRepository)
        .csrfTokenRequestHandler(requestHandler)
    );
  }
```

Refer to:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/exploits/csrf.html